# Javascript cannot find my imported constructor

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement model-view-control in a web app. I'm importing all the js in the bottom of the html but I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SideController is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:9)
```

I've posted my relevant code below. How can `SideController` not be found? It is imported in the exact same way as `SideBarView`, which seems to import successfully.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 sidebar collapse" id="sidebar">
      <div class="noofpeople">
        <div class="row noofpeople-wrapper">
          <h4>My Dinner</h4>
          <label>People <input id="numberOfGuests" type="number" class="form-control"></label><button type="button" id="plusButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button><button type="button" id="minusButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

  <!-- The application JavaScript code -->  
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      <script src="js/model/dinnerModel.js"></script>
      <script src="js/view/sidebarView.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controllers/sidebarController.js"</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

js/app.js:

```
$(function() {
    //We instantiate our model
    var model = new DinnerModel();
    // And create the instance of ExampleView
    var sidebar = $("#sidebar");
    if(sidebar[0] != undefined){
        var sidebarView = new SideBarView(sidebar, model);  
        var sidebarController = new SideController(sidebar, model);
    }

    var dishreel = $("#dishreel");
    if(dishreel[0] != undefined){
        var dishReelView = new DishReelView(dishreel, model);   
    }

});
```

js/controllers/sidebarController.js:

```
var SideController = function(container, model){
    var plusButton = container.find("#plusButton");
    var minusButton = container.find("#minusButton");
    plusButton.onclick = function(){
        model.incrNumberOfGuests();
    };
    minusButton.onclick = function(){
        model.decrNumberOfGuests();
    };
};
```

Comment: There's the missing `>` if nothing else; see how it's not rendering properly even here?

Answer (score 0):

I missed a `>` on the last import.